# ggplot2 plotting two vectors of different lengths from when the smaller one begins

Tags: r, vector, ggplot2

I am using R. I have a table of daily going back to 1900. Some of the vectors begin in 1900 some only begin in 1950 etc. I would like to plot each vector against the date vector. However, I would like each plot to begin when the y-vector begins and not always begin in 1900.

Here is an example:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("1/3/1928", "1/4/1928", "1/5/1928", "1/6/1928", 
"12/28/1927", "12/29/1927", "12/30/1927", "12/31/1927"), class = "factor"), 
DJIA = c(198.6, 199.96, 200.7, 202.4, 203.35, 202.24, 199.61, 
201.45), SPX = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 17.76, 17.72, 17.55, 17.66
)), .Names = c("Date", "DJIA", "SPX"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: please provide us with some data, so we can better address your question

Comment: Thank you @Jacob H for your interest. I'm not sure how to upload a csv file to this site so I will give a basic description. The first three columns of my csv file are Date, Dow Jones Industrial Average closing prices, and S&P 500 closing prices. The first two columns have data going back to 1900. The S&P, however, only began in 1928 and therefore has empty cells up until 1928. I'm using ggplot2 geom_line to plot each column against the date column. I would like the plot to begin at the first value for each column and not always begin in 1900.

Comment: TY @JacobH Not sure how to upload csv file so I will give an example. The first three columns are Date, Dow Jones Industrial Average closing prices, and S&P 500 closing prices. The first two columns have data going back to 1900. The S&P only began in 1928 and therefore has empty cells up until 1928. I'm using ggplot2 geom_line to plot each column against the date. I would like the plot to begin at the first value for each column and not always begin in 1900. ggplot(master,aes(date,SPX))+geom_line(stat="identity",na.rm=T)+scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%m/%d/%Y"),date_breaks='5 years')

Comment: Providing us with data is actually simple.  Use `dput`.  For example, if your data is `d <- data.frame(a = c(1,2), b = c("A", "B"))` pass `d` to `dput` (i.e. `dput(d)`).  Then copy the output and provided it within your questions.  In the current context, the output is `structure(list(a = c(1, 2), b = structure(1:2, .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")`.  This is what you're going to want to provide us.

Comment: its way to long. it doesn't even fit into the console window.

Comment: .Label = c("", "28.1%"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("DATE", 
"Percent.Gain.Loss", "X..of.Days", "Reversal.Pct", "DJIA", "Pt.Chg.", 

"AAII.Bullish.Average..St..Dev", "AAII.Bullish.Average..St..Dev.1"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -31984L))

Comment: that was the first and last part. There were many other names in middle @JacobH

Comment: First of all, you do not need to paste the output in a comment.  You can edit your question and therefore paste the output in your original question.  Second and most important, don't give use the whole data set.  Simplify the data set such that it still contains the core of your problem.  People on SO are eager to help but you gotta meet us halfway.

Comment: 455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 
    455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 455.646, 451.094, 
    451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 
    451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 
    451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 451.094, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)),.Names = c("DATE", 
"Percent.Gain.Loss", "X..of.Days", "Reversal.Pct", "DJIA", "Pt.Chg.", 
 
"NYSE.Margin.Debt"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1647L))

Comment: I'm new at this. I apologize. @JacobH I will try providing a simple example in the question.

Comment: No worries!  Writing an effective SO question is not always easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update!  Let me call your data `d`

```
d <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                              4L), .Label = c("1/3/1928", "1/4/1928", "1/5/1928", "1/6/1928", 
                                              "12/28/1927", "12/29/1927", "12/30/1927", "12/31/1927"), class = "factor"), 
           DJIA = c(198.6, 199.96, 200.7, 202.4, 203.35, 202.24, 199.61, 
                    201.45), SPX = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 17.76, 17.72, 17.55, 17.66
                    )), .Names = c("Date", "DJIA", "SPX"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                               -8L))
```

The first problem with this data is that `Date` is a factor, to plot correctly we need to first change it to a `Date`,

```
d$Date <- as.Date(d$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

The easiest way to achieve your desired output is to remove the `NA` as follows

```
 ggplot(d[complete.cases(d[,c("Date", "SPX")]), ], aes(x = Date, y = SPX)) +
   geom_line()
```

However, I suspect you'll be generating a lot of these figures.  It might be a better idea to create you own plot function.

```
myplot <- function(data, myX, myY){
  data <- data[complete.cases(data[,c(myX, myY)]), ]
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = myX, y = myY))+
    geom_line()
}
```

Notice the `aes_string`, this simplifies the passing of the variable names.  It is possible to use `aes`, but its a bit more complicated.

With this function you can plot each columns with the code

```
myCOL <- c("DJIA", "SPX") #names of columns, note they are in quotes.  This is because we're using aes_string

allPLOT <- lapply(myCOL, function(x) myplot(d, "Date", x))

names(allPLOT) <- myCOL #naming the elements of the list
```

All the plots are now stored in a list for example you can obtain the plot for `SPX` by calling

```
allPLOT$SPX
```

Comment: when I used your first version I got this error: geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: Thank you for your help @JacobH but when I tried your second version i got this error:      geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic? and though the x axis begins when the y values begin there is nothing displayed

Comment: I got it! For some reason I couldn

Comment: thank you again @JacobH. I got it! For some reason I couldn't use the date<-as.date function and therefore it was formatted as a value and not a date. I used data$Date<-as.date and for some reason that worked. However it only worked for the first version and not the second and you are right the second version would be a lot more helpful since I have over 70 columns

Comment: @MBA The reason you're getting the error is because `Date` is saved as a factor, be sure to change it to a date with `d$Date <- as.Date(d$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")`.  I've also updated the answer.  If you found the answer helpful be sure to accept it (by clicking the check mark) and upvote.

Comment: @MBA FYI `R` is case sensitive so `as.date` and `as.Date` are not equivalent.  After making this correction, both approaches should work, they do on my machine.

Comment: @MBA one last thing, you may want to check out the `cowplot` package.  It will allow you to combine each of your figures into one image.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I'm not sure how to use cowplot but I used grid.draw(rbind and that worked well. I just repeated the first method code and used excel to repeat the code inserting the column names. It worked.